# Having trouble configuring bot channels in Azure Portal

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am using a Visual Studio Dev Essentials, and I am trying to set a new QnaMaker bot avaiable on skype and webchat. I was doing all right during the preview, but
since bot general availability, every time I try to create a new QnAmaker Bot I get the same problem: I can´t set the channels for my QnA knowledge base. I can test, configure, and use any other option in the menu, but channels remains a blank screen. (I tried other browsers and I waited more than 10 minutes and it remains blank)

[image: Blank Channels Page]

Whether I try to create a new bot directly on Azure Portal or by BotFramework calling Azure Portal, either using Web App Bot or a Bot Channels Registrations, I get the same result.

I don´t know if this information is related or if it can be an useful hint to the problem, but using BotFramework I can acess configurantions and trash the old bots. All the new bots do not show the bucket and they go straight to Azure Portal when clicked.

[image: New Bots have no bucket]

I would appreciate any help or hint on this matter.

Thanks,
Carolina

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the actual Channel settings?

in dev.botframework.com/bots select the bot 

There you can configure the channels.

would be helpful if you posted a screenshot from it.

Comment: Post-GA, all bots must be created vis Azure Portal. The Bot Developer Portal, aka https://dev.botframework.com is deprecated. -- I'm unable to reproduce your error. When I create a new Web App Bot via Azure Portal, I am able to see the channel config page without error (Chrome browser). For reference, what browser are you using when you see the error? What other browsers did you test with? System info? Any additional details would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post a better channels settings screenshot because it doesn't load. It stays blank forever. 
I tried using azure portal too, and got the same results. I even asked a coleague to try via azure portal and  he got the same results. It seams there is some sort of obvious configuration that enables the channels setting we are skipping.
I am away till january 12, so I'll post more detais then. 
Meanwhile, there is some extra information I can provide: I tried Firefox, Edge and Chrome. All of them are with automatic updates turned on.  I use windows 10.
Tkanks for the inpus :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for nilsw and shawkyz1 for your inputs.

I came back from my vacations and I created again an all new Web App Bot using directly Azure Portal, since dev.botframework.com is deprecated.

I used the same Visual Studio Dev Essentials account, the same computer with Windows 10 Pro 64Gb, and the same Chrome version 63.0.3239.132 and Edge version 40.15063.674.0. After a little wait (about 3-5 minutes) I configured the QnA Knowledge Base and the Subscription Key, and it worked perfectly. The channels configuration is loading normally on Azure Portal.

Even the channels configuration for the chatbots I created before going on vacation are now correctly opening in Azure Portal.

It appears that all I lacked was patience to wait for the GA propagation to take place in all azure data centers.

Thanks Again.